# You tube API:Topic id is not displaying for autogenerated channels

Tags: youtube-api

used the following URL to get the topicid and details for auto generated channel. But its returning empty.

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=topicDetails&id=HC7Dr1BKwqctY&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Does somebody know how to get the topic details from above url. your help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like topicIds are only available for user channels, not autogenerated channels... if fact, other parts (contentDetails, etc.) aren't available either.

Comment: Agreed. Is there any way get the video list from auto generated channels ?

Comment: @MSNGeek where can i find the topic IDs please ?

Answer (score 0):

Ignore my comment on the question above; getting topic IDs from autogenerated channels works just fine in most cases, using the endpoint you've already listed; for example,

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=topicDetails&id=HCGV1V7wpRMrY&key={YOUR_KEY}
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=topicDetails&id=HCAh3LGI6q4g0&key={YOUR_KEY}
```

Both display the topicId as you would expect ... and I guess, if you really think about it, there's no reason it shouldn't, as the autogenerated channel uses the topicID to decide what videos make up the channel! So the real question is why this particular auto-generated channel isn't returning any topic details -- Freebase does have an ID for "sports," after all. It might be worth filing a bug noting that particular channel so the engineers can look into why it's not properly reporting what topicID it was based on.